# div scroll to in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scrollto

I have several divs with content. Some of the context is wrapped with,

```
content <a name='SomeName'> cool content </a> more content
```

In Javascript how do I force the SomeName name to scroll into view for that DIV only. The catch is that there are many DIVs on the page with content.

I have the Div's object known. The Div can contain other divs etc in a hierarchy. Somewhere in there is the SomeName anchor.

site: http://BiblePro.BibleOcean.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about scrollintoview command?  Not sure if thats IE specific.

document.getElementById("SomeName").scrollIntoView(true);

Answer (score 2):

You could set the Window Location to include the # anchor, and the browser will scroll to it.

```
Window.Location = "http://yourSite.com/YourPage.html#SomeName";
```