# How to use a dynamically generated id in window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have the following code in js and htm.

```html
<div id="div1_myDiv">This is my div1</div>
<div id="div2_myDiv">This is my div2</div>
<div id="div3_myDiv">This is my div3</div>

<div id="button1" onclick="openDiv('div1')">Show div1</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="openDiv('div2')">Show div2</div>
<div id="button3" onclick="openDiv('div3')">Show div3</div>
```

Whenever a button(div) is clicked, the page should scroll to the top of the div.

```js
function openDiv(divID) {
      var myDivID = "#" + divID + "_myDiv";
      window.location.href = myDivID;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work. Please advise a solution.

This question was marked as a duplicate of [div scroll to in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804474/div-scroll-to-in-javascript) but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you want to scroll the window (you use an anchor)? To open a popup (that's the function's title)? Please describe your goal more precisely.

Comment: Yes. Need to scroll the window to the top of the popup.

Comment: Is the code executed from the popup or from the *parent* window?

Comment: have you tried `window.location.hash = myDivID`

Comment: **[Works good here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9k8o48L2/1/)**

Comment: @vijayP thanks for the solution. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please modify your `function openDiv()` in following way:

```
function openDiv(divID) {
    var myDivID = "#" + divID + "_myDiv";
    window.location.hash = myDivID; //setting the location.hash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
**With the animation**

```
   function openDiv() {
           var myDivID = "#" + divID + "_myDiv";
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(myDivID).position().top}, 1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to scroll to the top of your window `window.location.href = "#"`
will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function popitup(url,windowName) {
       newwindow=window.open(url,windowName,'height=200,width=150');
       if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
       return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

"window.location.href" is use to change the current web page of the browser.
for your task, you can use the anchor tag element to show the div section. just like below,

```
    <div id="div1_myDiv">This is my div1</div>
    <div id="div2_myDiv">This is my div2</div>
    <div id="div3_myDiv">This is my div3</div>
    ...
    <a id="button1" href="#div1_myDiv">Show div1</a>
    <a id="button2" href="#div2_myDiv">Show div1</a>
    <a id="button3" href="#div3_myDiv">Show div1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `concate` myDivID in existing `URL`.

Try this solution

```js
function openDiv(divID) {
    //alert(divID);
    var myDivID = "#" + divID + "_myDiv";
    //window.location.hash = myDivID;
    window.location.href=window.location.href.concat('#Id');
    console.log(window.location.href);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1_myDiv">This is my div1</div>
<div id="div2_myDiv">This is my div2</div>
<div id="div3_myDiv">This is my div3</div>
...
<div id="button1" onclick="openDiv('div1')">Show div1</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="openDiv('div2')">Show div2</div>
<div id="button3" onclick="openDiv('div3')">Show div3</div>
```